# Angularjs - get data from oracle database

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs. I was wondering how can i get oracle database data using Angularjs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sukesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs is client side framework based on javascript. There is nothing to do retrieving data from Oracle. It is server side's duty.

You should implement on server side technologies such as .net or php, and give services to client side through web api, rest api etc.