# Upload a file (.csv) to MongoDB using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to create a simple app to upload CSV file using AngularJS.

Is it possible to upload a file into MongoDB using AngularJS?

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33142185/492258)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a server running with a API which communicates with your DB?

If not, no chance...

If yes, use a library like [Papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) to convert the csv file to a json object and send it via api to your mongoDB.